# Angular Update from 7 to 8, I got stuck angular-i18next

Tags: angular, version, updates, i18next

I got stuck in the middle of a longer trip. I started upgrading an angular application from version 6 to the current version (which is 12). I successfully changed from version 6 to 7, following the instructions on the https://update.angular.io/ website.
After successfully running the `ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8`update I tried to start the project. I got the following error:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/angular-i18next/I18NextService.d.ts:10:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

10     get options(): any;
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

I use the following i18next versions:

```
"angular-i18next": "^8.0.1",
"i18next": "^11.10.2",
"i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^2.2.4",
"i18next-xhr-backend": "^1.5.1",
```

Have somebody ever meat with this error? I already tried to change the version of typescript without success. I would be really happy if somebody could help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the version of angular-i18next. It was too high, so I downgraded to ^7.0.0, and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the version of "i18next": "^11.10.2" its incompatible and is looking for the angular 11 library.

Instead use "i18next": "^8.0.1" which is your main angular version.

you may have other issues if you keep going so set your version tree around 8 in your package.json file delete the node_modules folder and run npm install again and you should be okay.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer. The problem was with the version of angular-i18next. It was too high, so I downgraded to ^7.0.0, and it resolved the problem. I don't think that your idea would be good, because the i18next is a common library, and the version number is not synchronized  with the angular versions. The "i18next": "^8.0.1" was released 4 years ago, but the angular 8 in 2019. :)

Comment: well at least you got it, but stepping full platform steps backward is a problem I missed in your question the part of angular version 12 - for some reason I thought your version was 8.  have you thought about maybe just killing your node_modules folder and reinstalling to the correct platform version?  Sometimes these older modules in my experience have remnants that don't get cleaned up and create problems.  We moved to 39 apps to our user acceptance testing environment with Angular 12...ivy is excellent so far... our problem now is a postcss issue with a moderate warning and no fix yet. 

Comment: I tried to remove the node_modules folder but it seams that there a lot of "old"  package. Now I faced with the next issue. What about the ng2-lazy-trumbowyg package? I think it is no more compatible with angular 8. Do you think that I need to switch to an alternative?

Comment: I would - I think over time you should really keep up to date, because if these packages are no longer maintained their could become security issues.  its circular integration and maintenance in an app, keep updating all the time - even if its small seemingly insignificant changes.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you.  :) Thank you for your opinion and advice.